# Rotating Figure About Given Region R1 About OA

Tags: calculus

[Problem Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOci2.png)

I'm trying to figure out what to do for this certain problem. In the example that was posted, they got x^2 out of nowhere. As seen in the picture below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[Problem Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYfPS.png)

Answer (score 0):

In picture $2$ they have rotated region $R_1$ about the $x$-axis.  So it's just $\int_0^1\pi x^2\operatorname {dx}$, by circular disks.

Note, $R_1$ is just the region between the line $y=x$ and the $x$-axis, between $0$ and $1$.

Picture $1$ is different: instead of $y=x$ we have $y=4x$.

Comment: Why do you take out the 4 and multiply it in (4x)^2 though?? I'm confused where the radical of root 4 x comes into play.

Comment: Yes, I see that y=4x now. I am confused as to where the radicand of root 4 comes into play though?

Comment: Well, in picture $1$, we get  $\int_0^1\pi (4x)^2\operatorname {dx}$.  They don't seem to have used $R_2$ at all.  It seems there may be an error.  I get $\dfrac{16\pi}3$.

Comment: I got 16pi/3 too. However, I don't see how it is (4x)^2 when the line is just the slope of x right? It looks like the slope is just x instead of 4x which would be steeper, am I right?

Comment: Essentially, my question is where do you get the "4" from in the (4x)^2?

Comment: Oh, well, it would be $\int_0^1\pi y^2\operatorname{dx}$.  But $y=4x$.

Comment: Where do you get y = 4x? There's a 4 on the top right-hand corner of the square.

Comment: There's no hint or *clue* as to which is y=4x...It doesn't even say y=4x in the picture...

Comment: Sorry I'm just confused as to how you got that OTL *rolls eyes*

Comment: @Alexandra I know region $R_1$ is bounded by $OA$ and $y=4x$, because $y=4x$ is the line through the origin and $(1,4)$.

Comment: $R_2$ and $R_3$ don't seem to have come into play yet.

Comment: Is that because the slope is rise/run and you would do 4/1 (the y-value over the x value of (1,4)) ????

Comment: That's correct.